# Question about K&R - redirect input

Tags: c

In section 1.6 of 'The C Programming Language' (K&R) there is an example program and the authors state:

```
The output of this program ON ITSELF is
    digits = 9 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1, white space = 123, other = 345
```

Then there are many similar programs etc. including exercises. I understand everything about the logic of the code and can do the exercises, but how do I actually test my program on a file like the authors or many others on the web?

Edit: The question should be: How can I redirect the input of a file to the program?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you asking how to compile and run a C program?

Comment: Does [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) mean anything to you? The book assumes you are working in a CLI. Working in a GUI presents a few more challenges, not really related to the C language. You may want to set up your system such that working in a CLI environment is easy.

Comment: The shown example uses getchar() to read chars from input, does something and then uses putchar() to print chars. And the author says he uses an actual file, from which he gets the chars and acts as it is clear how to do this. I'm asking how I can do this too, because I have no idea how to do it. I think it has to do with the operating system and not the C language.

Comment: that's redirection rather than arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program in chapter 1.6 reads input from stdin. To make it read from a file, you can (on most operating systems) redirect stdin to be a file by running your program like this:

```
myprogram < somefile
```

Or you can pipe the content of a file to it like so:

```
cat somefile | myprogram
```

On windows, you'd use the `type` program instead of `cat`,

```
type somefile | myprogram
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 'myprogram < somefile' is what I was looking for. I'm using Mac OS X.

Comment: Note: You really shouldn't use `cat` (or `type`) like that unless your shell doesn't support file redirection (nearly all do); see [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html). +1 for `<` though.

Answer (score 2):

This is using re-direction. Instead of the input to the program coming from the keyboard it comes from a file.

At the DOS prompt:-

C:>myexe < filename

Get to the DOS prompt in Windows use the command shell. Or start Run.. and enter cmd

On a Mac this is called terminal (type "terminal" into Searchlight to get to it).

Answer (score 2):

By default, your program will take input from stdin, which is a buffer which is filled based on input from your keyboard (by default). However, you can also tell your program to fill stdin from a text file instead.

**Using a *nix based system**, you can simply create a text file, and save it as whatever you'd like, "test_input" for instance. Fill it with the input that you'd like to pass to your program, save it, and then run your program like this:

```
./a.out < test_input
```

This is called redirection because you are "redirecting" (if you will) the input to come from a file, rather than the default (keyboard). It goes both ways, you can also redirect your output to a file, rather than stdout with the other angle bracket, '>'.

**Using Visual Studio**, and not popping open a command prompt to do something like the command above, you can use a C++ ifstream, put the text file in the local directory, and then simply use the ifstream everywhere instead of stdin:

```
ifstream sin("test_input.txt" , ifstream::in);
int value;
sin >> value;
```

You can output to a file using an ofstream.

Note that ifstreams and ofstreams are C++ objects, and can't be used in C. While you can write to files and read from files in C, it's a little trickier than simply replacing all instances of cout and cin. You actually have to think about what you are reading and writing :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanations too, arasmussen.